# How to set the Divider (to null) of a ListFragment custom layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, android-adapter

I'm trying to understand how to work with listfragments and custom adapters. So I build this little example and I was wondering where I could set the divider of my listview to null.

I found different ways:
- android:dividerHeight="1dip"
- android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
But i dont have an XML layout with listview

I also saw something like listview.setDivider(null), but I dont know where I can use that method in my code because of the use of listfragments.

My code:

```
listview_item_row.xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CountryList class

```
public class CountryList extends ListFragment {

    Country[] countries2 = new Country[]
            {
                new Country("Netherlands"),
                new Country(R.drawable.bas,"Basque Country")
            };


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        CountryAdapter adapter = new CountryAdapter(inflater.getContext(),R.layout.listview_item_row,countries2);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        getListView().setDivider(null);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

My CountryAdapter

```
public class CountryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country>{

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Country[] data = null;

public CountryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Country[] data) {
    super(context,layoutResourceId,data);
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row = convertView;
    CountryHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

        holder = new CountryHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivCountry);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);

        row.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (CountryHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Country country = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(country.getTitle());
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(country.getIcon());

    return row;

}

static class CountryHolder
{
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can always set a custom view for the ListFragment by returning a view on onCreateView() but you need to have a ListView in it with a "@id/android:list" like explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html).

In your xml you could do `android:divider="@null"` or in if you really want to do it in your ListFragment code `getListView().setDivider(null);` (in onActivityCreated() method).

Comment: I tried adding the getListView().setDivider(null) (see my code "content view not yet created") but that gives me an error. I'm a little bit confused. I understand that I need to point to a xml layout with a listview, but where do I do that? And if i make a xml layout with a listview, where do I put my listview_item_row.xml ?

Comment: Instead of calling `getListView().setDivider(null);` in `onCreateView`, call it in `onActivityCreated` and that should fix the problem.  I make it a point to never touch the `onCreateView` function inside a `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 3):

Inside `onCreateView` use:

`getListView().setDivider(null);`

Comment: you forgot the parentheses?

Comment: thank you too! you still gave an answer in the right direction :)